# How to use MPI_Info_set with MPI_Comm_spawn in MPICH

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, spawn, mpich

I need to use MPI spawn on a cluster. For that I understood I need to use MPI_Info_set to specify with nodes will run the spawned processes. I have tried `MPI_Info_set(info, "add-host","node1,node2")` but it does not work.

Below, I provide a small example of the spawning code:

```
MPI_Info info;
MPI_Info_create(&info);
MPI_Info_set(info,"add-host","node1,node2");
MPI_Comm_spawn("./mpiworker", MPI_ARGV_NULL,
               dynamic_procs,
               info, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
               &intercomm,
               MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);
```

Is there anything else I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Parameter `add-host` comes probably from OpenMPI ([man page](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/current/man3/MPI_Comm_spawn.3.php)) and it is not supported in MPICH.

For MPICH try one of those:

- `host` - works for me,
- `hosts` - should work, however, it seems that it is broken in version I currently use and MPI spawns all processes at the first node passed as a parameter value; if it also happens in your case, I suggest manual assignment of hosts for each process using `MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple`.

Also, I have no idea how to find a list of all supported parameters - I think MPICH guys do not pay much attention to keep documentation complete.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me, instead of just `MPI_Comm_spawn`. The following code will spawn 1 process per node. I could spawn more processes per node by extending the dimension of the inputs below.

```
MPI_Info info[2];

MPI_Info_create(&info[0]);
MPI_Info_set(info[0],"host","node1");

MPI_Info_create(&info[1]);
MPI_Info_set(info[1],"host","node2");

char *cmds[2] = { "./mpiworker", "./mpiworker" };
int np[2] = { 1, 1 };
int errcodes[2];

MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple( 2, cmds, MPI_ARGVS_NULL, np, info, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &intercomm, errcodes );

//Below parallel code follows
...
```

> The above was tested on Ubuntu-bionic with MPICH Version:3.3a2.

My example is based on the following [page](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple.html). If I find a more elegant way, I will repost.